# Smoothing/interpolating raster in Python using GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, interpolation

I am developing in Python and using GDAL from OSGEO to manipulate and interact with rasters and shapefiles.

I want to take a shapefile that has point features and interpolate it into a surface raster.  Right now I am using the method 'RasterizeLayer' which burns a value from the point feature into the raster (which is set with all nodata values) but leaves all untouched pixels as a 'nodata' value.  I am therefore left with a checkerboard type raster.

What I have after using RasterizeLayer:

[image: [Raster from using gdal.rasterizelayer]]

What I want for a final product:

[image]

I believe the function I am looking for is known as 'Spline_sa()' from the arcgisscripting import.

Does GDAL have a similar function, or is there a different method to get my desired output?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd take a look at NumPy and Scipy - there's a good example of interpolating point data in the [SciPy Cookbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312003432/http://www.scipy.org:80/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data) using the [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) function. Obviously this requires that you have the data in a numpy array;

- Using the GDAL python bindings you can read your data into Python
  using `gdal.Dataset.ReadAsArray()` for a raster.
- With OGR you would loop through the feature layer and extracting point data from the shapefile (or better yet, write the shapefile to a CSV using `GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ` [see the [OGR CSV file format]](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) and read the csv into Python).

Once you've got a gridded output you can then use GDAL to write the resulting numpy array to a raster.

Lastly, if you don't have any luck with the Scipy interpolate library, you could always try [scipy.ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I am giving the Scipy.interpolate.griddata approach a whirl. I will post back my results.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to get back to this post. The answer above is basically what I did to solve my problem.  I used the Scipy interpolate library to fill in those nodata spaces and then wrote it back to the rasterband.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Doug No worries - happy to healp!

Comment: How fast is this solution? Can it be used for 10k x 10k grid where only every 100x100 is known value? I tried gdal_fillnodata which is incredibly fast compared to any interpolation but it doesn't work well for too sparse points. At this moment I am using triangulation from Saga but it is very slow for medium arrays and fail with big ones.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the [GDAL gridding API](https://gdal.org/tutorials/gdal_grid_tut.html). I don't know if that is exposed in the Python bindings, but if not, you call call the [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) utility via the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

GDAL grid API only uses Inverse Distance Weighting, Moving Average and Nearest Neighbour, it doesn't implement splines.  Another option is to use [Scipy](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028024944/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

Answer (score 2):

A bit old to this thread but I have written a simple module that uses the KNN algorithm from sklearn called skspatial.

https://github.com/rosskush/skspatial

You can import a shapefile using geopandas and select a column and it will interpolate a surface that can be exported to a raster. It's very basic and probably not the best way to do it, but it keeps everything pure python at least.